AzureFunctions v4でPOSTされた画像ファイルを受け取る方法を教えて下さい。
AzureFunctionsのNode.jsのv4モデルでPOSTされた画像を受取、保存するプログラムを書いたのですが、上手く行きません。
Fileは作成されるのですが、Jpegファイルとして読めません。
作成されたファイルを無理やりVSCodeで読むと以下のような中身となっており、余分なHeaderやBoundaryが追加されているようです。
------WebKitFormBoundaryWidmPeTqkW2p2zCD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

����　以下文字化け

調べたところ、busboyで分解するようなのですが、v4で上手く動かすことができません。
どなたか分かる方教えて下さい。
クライアントプログラム
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    <button id="uploadButton">Upload</button>
    <img id="uploadedImage" src="" alt="Uploaded Image" style="display:none;">

    <script>
        document.getElementById('uploadButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
            const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            const file = fileInput.files[0];

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', file);

            const response = await fetch('/api/message', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });
            const result = await response.text();
            alert(result);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

サーバー（AzureFunctions）プログラム
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
app.setup({ enableHttpStream: true });
const { createWriteStream } = require('fs');
const { Writable } = require('stream');

app.http('message', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        const writeStream = createWriteStream('sample.jpg');
        const webWriteStream = Writable.toWeb(writeStream);
        await request.body.pipeTo(webWriteStream);
        return {body: `Uploaded file: sample.jpg`};
    }
});

